# Fast algorithm to invert a large sparse matrix

Tags: matrices, number-theory, algorithms, numerical-methods, matrix-equations

I am interesting in sparse matrix that defined at [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix). I am looking for a fast algorithm to invert the matrix (better than [Gaussian Elimimation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination)). Could you suggest to me some methods that reduce computational time? Note that the matrix is sparse and large. For example $100 \times 100$ or $500\times500$. Thanks

Comment: $500\times 500$ matrices are not large at all (unless you want to invert them by hand or on some prehistoric machine). In any case, there are sparse variants of GE.

Comment: Thanks for comment. However, I just give the example. My matrix can be 1000 by 1000 or more. The main point is that the matrix is sparse matrix. I hope I can find a fast algorithm for the special matrix

Comment: Yes, sparse LU. E.g., [here](http://faculty.cse.tamu.edu/davis/suitesparse.html), [here](http://crd-legacy.lbl.gov/~xiaoye/SuperLU/), [here](http://www.hsl.rl.ac.uk/catalogue/), [here](http://mumps.enseeiht.fr/index.php?page=home),... Iterative methods might be faster but without further information on how special the considered sparse matrices are, it is impossible to say. First thing to try are sparse direct solvers anyway; MATLAB has also a collection of sparse solvers based on SuiteSparse.